# Progressive numbering in nested lists

Tags: numbering, enumerate, itemize

I have this code:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First sub-item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Second sub-item
        \item Third sub-item
        \item Fourth sub-item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

...but I want numbers in nested lists to be progressive and not to reset every time. Is there any way to do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

`resume` from `enumitem` package seems to work:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}  %%% <-
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First sub-item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Item
        \begin{enumerate}[resume] %<-
        \item Second sub-item
        \item Third sub-item
        \item Fourth sub-item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]